# SQL Server Graph DB find all path with fix start and end node

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-graph

**I have a sql graph db as follow:**
[image]

**Below is my sql script:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Person;
CREATE TABLE Person (userName VARCHAR(100)  PRIMARY KEY) AS NODE;

INSERT INTO Person (userName) VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'); 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Follow; 
CREATE TABLE Follow AS EDGE;

INSERT INTO Follow ($from_id, $to_id) VALUES (
   (SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'A'),
   (SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'E')),

   ((SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'E'),
   (SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'C')),


   ((SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'C'),
   (SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'A')),


   ((SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'A'),
   (SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'F')),

   ((SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'F'),
   (SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'B')),

   ((SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'B'),
   (SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'F')),

   ((SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'B'),
   (SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'E')),

   ((SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'E'),
   (SELECT $node_id FROM dbo.Person WHERE userName = 'B'));
```

**What I have try:** 
Following query that I have try only able to give me shortest path of each node that end with node C.

```
SELECT
    username, StartNode, [Edges Path], FinalNode, Levels
FROM (
    SELECT 
        P1.username, 
        P1.username as StartNode, 
        STRING_AGG(P2.userName,'->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Edges Path],
        LAST_VALUE(P2.userName) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS FinalNode,
        COUNT(P2.userName) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS Levels
    FROM
        Person P1,
        Person FOR PATH P2,
        Follow FOR PATH Follow
    WHERE 
        MATCH(SHORTEST_PATH(P1(-(Follow)->P2)+))
 ) AS Q
 WHERE Q.FinalNode = 'C'
```

**What I intend to achieve:**

1. Find **ALL** path that start with node C
2. Find **ALL** path that end with node C

The key thing here is that I want to find all path that start with C and end with C. I expect that I could achieve ***(2)*** by change the above query by changing **SHORTEST_PATH** to **ALL_PATH** but there is no such method exist. On the other hand, I have no idea of how to achieve ***(1)***.

How can I achieve what I wanted?

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of below?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632206/sql-server-graph-query-find-all-paths-to-node